# GOOGLE Place Api: how to add more place names against single place by google place actions

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

How to add one place name as a primary in English and then different names on different languages for same place by Google place actions. It could be primary or not primary on different languages.
Or Google does the same for us.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am not asking to get Place detail, I mean to ask how to add more names for single place. For example I have added a place name ("New Software Solution") through the Place Actions by providing Language as English. I get the response {id, reference, status}. I want to add more names for the same place. i.e. I want to add another name in Arabic for the same place. How I can do it? I will be highly thankful if I could get some examaples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own WindowAdapter for Marker which has 2 line of name (for example)

here is MyInfoWIndowAdapter

```
public class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View mView;

    public MyInfoWindowAdapter(Activity activity) {

        mView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        String title = marker.getTitle();
        final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        final TextView titleUi1 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final TextView titleUi2 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
        titleUi1.setText(title);
        titleUi2.setText("Second name");
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

the custom_info_window:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/map_info_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/map_info_window_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/map_info_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/map_info_window_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/map_info_snippet"
        android:textSize="@dimen/map_info_window_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

on Mapfragment, add this at onCreate

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Comment: I need in javascript or in C# if possible

Comment: @user2378154 this example come from android. I don't know javascript/C#

Comment: I am still stuck and need the same feature using google place api as map maker provides to add more names for single places. (See the multiple name section)  <<https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/1096113?hl=en&ref_topic=2889732>>